# How to navigate users into Sharepoint by using tokens

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to build a small client application(HTML, Javascript) to navigate users into Sharepoint online. I have already built a token generation system using Microsoft's token generation system which gives me access to Sharepoint online and I have tested successfully using Postman. Now, I want to use the same system to pre-authenticate users and navigate them to Sharepoint site directly by using the bearer token generated.

This is what I have done to generate the token -

- Register my app in Azure AD on the Management Portal to get
  client_id, client_secret, redirectUri and the right permissions on
  Office 365 for sites.
- Call the authorization endpoint at
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
- Call the token service endpoint at
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
- Call the SharePoint REST endpoint with the access token https://xxxx/sites/xxxx/_api/web/

Any idea or resources related to this is greatly appreciated.